# convert date to unix time stamp in nvd3 x-axis

Tags: nvd3.js

Here I'm getting date as 1970-01-01 by default.Can anyone please help me out in converting "2015-10-01" to timestamp.

My date :

```
"date": "2015-10-01"


xAxis: {
                axisLabel: 'Months',
                ticks: d3.time.months,
                tickFormat: function (d) {                    



                   return  d3.time.format('%Y %b')(new Date(d));

                }
```

I did this thing,which solved my issue

```
x: function (d) { return  d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d').parse(d.date); },
            y: function (d) { return d.trendingValue; },
           useInteractiveGuideline: true,
           xScale: d3.time.scale(),
            xAxis: {
                axisLabel: 'Months',
                ticks: d3.time.months,
                tickFormat: function (d) {                    

                   return  d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(d));

                }
            }
```

Comment: can anyone please help me out ..

Comment: can you post a Fiddle or complete code?

Comment: My issue got resolved .after editing to above code

Comment: If you solve your problem post an answer not edit the question